# jayway library | Reading a JSON from JSONPath

Tags: java, jsonpath, jayway

I am using jayway library as I have to use JSONPath Expressions.

```
{
"fruit":"Apple",
"size":"Large",
"price":"40"
}
```

Above is my json, now from this JSON suppose I want to read from a specific path.
For Ex: - $.fruit
So the code snippet will be like
Assuming I have read the json file and and it is stored here after converting it to string.

```
String sb ="input json";
DocumentContext context = JsonPath.parse(sb);
Object rawData = context.read(path);
```

Considering this will give me String as it is definte path.
I will have **"Apple"** stored in **"sb"**

Now what if I want to add this String value to a different JSON which will have only this element in it. Using jayway library classes.

```
    {
      "fruit":"Apple"
    }
```

1. I tried context.set method to add but it will give me all elements.
2. Also tried context.remove method but for that I will have to specifically provide the remaining path.
   (if there is any negate condition like context.remove(!"$.fruit") which will remove every element aprat from fruit), I think I can still achieve but couldn't find that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: use `context.put` on a new context, instead of `context.set`.

---

Details:

If you want to create a new JSON object containing `{"fruit":"Apple"}`, you can take your starting point and extend it as follows:

```java
String sb = " { \"fruit\":\"Apple\", \"size\":\"Large\", \"price\":\"40\" }";
DocumentContext context = JsonPath.parse(sb);
String key = "fruit";
Object rawData = context.read("$." + key);
        
// create a new context containing an empty JSON object:
DocumentContext context2 = JsonPath.parse("{}");
// add your JSON to the root of the object:
context2.put("$", key, rawData);
// print the result:
System.out.println(context2.jsonString());
```

This outputs the following:

```
{"fruit":"Apple"}
```

---

I don't know of a path operator which means "*everything except*" the one thing you want to keep. If you wanted to go this way, maybe you would have to iterate the original JSON and delete each object which does not equal the data to be kept.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but here can we do soemthing which will create a json for me using jsonpath only, as this will be a user input which will be json path ("$.fruit")

        `context2.put(path,rawData)`

Comment: Do we have any utility which will get me the last key in jsonPath.

Comment: requirement got changed and I dont have to add that key back :p, thanks for the input, although would love to know if there is any utility which can give child key.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider another library *Josson* for simpler syntax.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString("{\"fruit\":\"Apple\", \"size\":\"Large\", \"price\":\"40\"}");
JsonNode node = josson.getNode("map(fruit)");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
{
  "fruit" : "Apple"
}
```

Comment: Does it provide functionality to remove a element from given Json Path ?

Comment: Yes, function `field(key1:, key2:, ...)`.